# INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables take so long when used in certain ways

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

While attempting to find better ways to parse table schema data, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` articles were tested.

There must be way more going on behind the scenes then meets the eye. Using sys.* articles, being more verbose, are all reliably fast.

Can anyone explain why using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` articles produce a query plan the size of a Texas roadmap (see paste a plan)?

Also, the storing the output of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` into a #temp or @temp table reduces the query time from 8 minutes to 6 seconds when joined against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE`.

Here is a paste the plan -> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyRUqcEd6

The first query takes 2 seconds.
The second query takes over 8 minutes.

```
DECLARE @X TABLE(TableName NVARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @X 
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME AS TableName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 

----2 Seconds 740 Rows
SELECT 
    CU.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName,
    T.TableName AS TableName
FROM    
    @X T
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CS ON CS.TABLE_NAME = T.TableName
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CS.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND CS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'  

GO

----8:47 Seconds 740 Rows
SELECT 
    CU.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName,
    T.TABLE_NAME AS TableName
FROM    
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CS ON CS.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CS.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND CS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

[image]

Comment: Were you running something else concurrently for the second one? 7mins 14secs of `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` waits won't help

Comment: Ahhh, that dev box is undersized and as a bloated job that runs every 15 minutes against 100+ databases. I bet the query was just got caught up with some churn. When that job runs, none of the tables or views nodes can be expanded for any database in the object explorer.

Comment: Can you repro the same dismal performance when that isn't running? Or somewhat less dismal? I do tend to avoid `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as much more efficient to join on indexed ids than strings but this diff sounds excessive!

Comment: I can regularly reproduce the diff between the two queries. When the job was not running, the second query returned in half the time or 4:37 seconds.

Comment: And yeah that bit of the plan that reads 294,147,504 rows (across 633 executions) and takes 7:59 is interesting - especially as the join above it ends up returning 0 rows

Comment: @MartinSmith - I've found a better way to do this. The question was a matter of curiosity. There is really no telling how many profiling tools/odd jobs and whatnot running on that machine, however, I ran the same queries almost 6 months ago with similar results.

Comment: The execution plan for just `select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` is pretty large - but if you look at `exec sp_helptext 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE'` you can see why.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Ow wow, thanks, it is a bit more transparent now. That server has close to 200 databases with 640 or more tables each.

Comment: You should generally avoid the information_schema views: [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)